# Regex not finding all values in Google search results?

Tags: php, regex, screen-scraping

First of all, I should stress that I'm trying to learn here, not be malicious or spam anyone.

I'm trying to learn about regex in Google search results by finding email addresses using the following code. However, sometimes it only finds some of the email addresses, other times not at all.

If I try it with a Wikipedia URL then I don't have a problem.

```
$url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=hello@hotmail.com";
// $url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address"; this works fine
$string = file_get_contents($url);

$matches = array();
$pattern = '/[a-z\d._%+-]+@[a-z\d.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}\b/i';
preg_match_all($pattern,$string,$matches);

foreach ($matches as $row)
{
    foreach ($row as $row2)
    {
        echo $row2."<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: First off, I do hope you're not spamming anyone, secondly, for us to debug this we'd need a sample email address that this hasn't pulled out (change some of the [a-z] letters around for privacy)

Comment: Hi Mike, as an example, if you look at this results page you'll see the second and fourth to bottom results contain email addresses (vam****.s**er1@hotmail.com and dok*****zmi@hotmail.com). Those aren't being returned by the script. https://www.google.com/search?q=hello@hotmail.com - that query returns hello@hotmail.com three times.

Comment: I'd feel more comfortable, if you were testing/debugging this with fictional e-mails.

Comment: Sure, happy to do that - how might I go about it?

Comment: Try [this site](http://www.fakemailgenerator.com/). The same concept should work.

Comment: It works fine with any email that that site generates. I think this is a problem with Google search results in particular.

Comment: yep, one of the examples you gave has <em> tags in it probably to stop exactly this kind of parsing. see updated answer.

Comment: Have you checked the `file_get_contents($url)` does actually contain the emails you want in the format you want? Google doesn't like being parsed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing uppercase:

```
'/[A-Za-z\d._%+-]+@[A-Za-z\d.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}\b/i'
```

I put it in everywhere in case you want to match HELLO@GMAIL.COM, you can always downcase it.

EDIT: I think I was trying to solve this for a different email address which wasn't being matched

EDIT 2: search the html, those that don't work have emphasis like `example<em>@example.com</em>` so won't parse.

Comment: Thanks, that's useful to add in. Unfortunately it didn't catch any more email addresses though.

Comment: Re your edit 2 - I think that's the solution. Is there a way to strip tags before doing the regex?

Comment: sure, you could do some replacements but you're likely to mange your html (as in remove all <em> and </em> tags and other things that you think aren't relevant.)

Comment: Thanks, I went for `$string = str_ireplace('<em>','',$string); $string = str_ireplace('</em>','',$string); $string = str_ireplace('<b>','',$string); $string = str_ireplace('</b>','',$string);`